# I can't seem to access a web application externally

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis, windows-server-2003

I am getting a "Server Unavailable" error message when I try to access a web application externally, but I can access it fine internally. It's got a message for administrators telling me to check the event log, but there's nothing there. Another thing, this is a work server, so I'm not exactly sure if they're using another firewall, but the Windows Firewall is disabled and the McAfee security installation does not have a firewall. Any thoughts on what could be causing this. If you need to see any code or need more information, let me know.The server is running Windows 2003 server OS.

Answer (score 0):

I would be willing to bet the correct ports are not forwarded.

What kind of web app is it?  You have to find out which port that app uses and forward it on the router.

Comment: It's an ASP.NET web application coded in C#. But how do I check where the ports are forwarded?

Comment: On a windows machine run ipconfig in the command prompt, and look at the default gateway.

Note the address and type it in to your browser and then poke around your router settings

Answer (score 0):

**Server Application Unavailable in IIS for ASP.NET application**

Problem :Server Application Unavailable

The web application you are attempting to access on this web server is currently unavailable. Please hit the "**Refresh**" button in your web browser to retry your request.

*Administrator Note:* An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server. Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.

**Solution 1:**
Open the command promt and direct to the folder C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
and run the command to install ASP.NET in your IIS
aspnet_regiis.exe -i

**Solution 2:**
To work around this problem, verify that the ASPNET account has the correct user rights as follows:

a) %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\Version\Temporary ASP.NET Files: Full Control
%windir%\Temp: Full Control

b) Application folder: Read

c) %installroot% hierarchy (for example, %windir%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\Version): Read

d) %windir%\Assembly: Read

e) Web site root (for example, %root%\Inetpub\Wwwroot) or the path that the default Web site points to: Read

f) %windir%\System32: Read(Typically, the ASPNET account has already been granted user rights as a member of the Users group.)

Now Close all the applications and reset IIS in command promt 'iisreset'

problem solved :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing service unavailable, simply check your App Pool